# SparkSQL: intra-SparkSQL-application table registration

Tags: apache-spark-sql

**Context.** I have tens of SQL queries stored in separate files. For benchmarking purposes, I created an application that iterates through each of those query files and passes it to a standalone Spark application. This latter first parses the query, extracts the used tables, registers them (using: `registerTempTable()` in Spark < 2 and `createOrReplaceTempView()` in Spark 2), and executes effectively the query (`spark.sql()`).

**Challenge.** Since registering the tables can be time consuming, I would like to *lazily* register the tables, i.e. only *once* when they are *first* used, and keep that in form of metadata that can readily be used in the subsequent queries without the need to re-register the tables with each query. It's a sort of intra-job caching but not any of the caching options Spark offers (table caching), as far as I know.

Is that possible? if not can anyone suggest another approach to accomplish the same goal (iterating through separate query files and run a querying Spark application without registering the tables that have already been registered before).

Comment: I comment to my own question. I've come across Named RDDs/Objects provided by [Spark Job Server](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver#named-objects). Haven't tried them myself, but anyone passing by this question in the future might would like to have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

In general, registering a table should not take time (except if you have lots of files it might take time to generate the list of file sources). It is basically just giving the dataframe a name. What would take time is reading the dataframe from disk.

So the basic question is, how is the dataframe (tables) written to disk. If it is written as a large number of small files or a file format which is slow (e.g. csv), this can take some time (having lots of files take time to generate the file list and having a "slow" file format means the actual reading is slow).

So the first thing you can try to do is read your data and resave it.
lets say for the sake of example that you have a large number of csv files in some path. You can do something like:

```
 df = spark.read.csv("path/*.csv")
```

now that you have a dataframe you can change it to have less files and use a better format such as:

```
df.coalesce(100).write.parquet("newPath")
```

If the above is not enough, and your cluster is large enough to cache everything, you might put everything in a single job, go over all tables in all queries, register all of them and cache them. Then run your sql queries one after the other (and time each one separately).

If all of this fails you can try to use something like alluxio (http://www.alluxio.org/) to create an in memory file system and try to read from that.

Comment: Thanks Assaf. In fact, each table is saved as one Parquet table, so not many files. Even with that, it is taking time for some queries I ran. I've monitored the table registration and I can tell that for some queries, they take time, of course it's still in the scale of few seconds, but for interactive querying, that is already long---for some queries it takes the same or even more time than it takes to execute the query.

Comment: Also, indeed I could put everything in a single job and that should be slved, but that goes against our benchmarking protocol, where the execution job should be a standalone (Spark) application that takes as args the path to the database (parquet tables) and the query to execute against the latter database, and the iteration over the SQL query files is done via a Shell script. Hence the intra-job table registration problem I'm asking help/guidance in.